# C++ iterator in loop

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

+++ See update below +++

This is a code for reverse printing the content of an array. I used 3 slightly different methods for doing it: directly putting the dimension of the array in the for loop, using iterator and using reverse_iterator and measured the execution time of printing the for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using get_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter the array dimension:";
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;

    //Read the array elements
    std::cout << "Enter the array elements:" <<'\n';
    std::vector <int> v;
    int input;
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++){
        std::cin >> input;
        v.push_back(input);
    }

    auto start = get_time::now();
    for(int i=N-1; i>=0; i--){
        std::cout << v[i] <<" ";
    }
    auto finish = get_time::now();
    auto time_diff=finish-start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time,non-iterator= " << std::chrono::duration<double>
        (time_diff).count() << " Seconds" << '\n';

    auto start2 = get_time::now();
    std::vector <int>::reverse_iterator ri;
    for(ri=v.rbegin(); ri!=v.rend(); ri++){
        std::cout << *ri <<" ";
    }
    auto finish2 = get_time::now();
    auto time_diff2=finish2-start2;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time, reverse iterator= " << std::chrono::duration<double>
        (time_diff2).count() << " Seconds" << '\n';

    auto start3 = get_time::now();
    std::vector <int>::iterator i;
    for(i=v.end()-1; i>=v.begin(); i--){
        std::cout << *i <<" ";
    }
    auto finish3 = get_time::now();
    auto time_diff3=finish3-start3;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time, iterator= " << std::chrono::duration<double>
        (time_diff3).count() << " Seconds" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Output:
5 4 3 2 1 Elapsed time,non-iterator= 2.7913e-05 Seconds
5 4 3 2 1 Elapsed time, reverse iterator= 5.57e-06 Seconds
5 4 3 2 1 Elapsed time, iterator= 4.56e-06 Seconds
```

My question is: 
Why the direct method is almost 5 times slower than both iterator and reverse_iterator methods? Also, is this faster execution of iterator machine dependent?

This is a prototype, but I will need to deal with much bigger matrices; that is why I am asking this question. Thank you.

+++ Update +++

I am posting the updated results after incorporating the comments. It was too big for a comment.

I changed the for loop to evaluate the sum of an array with 100000 elements. I evaluated the same sum using the above mentioned methods (compiled with -O3 in clang++) and I have averaged the execution time for 3 methods over 10000 runs. Here are the results:

```
Average (10000 runs) elapsed time, non-iterator= 2.50183e-05
Average (10000 runs) elapsed time, reverse-iterator= 3.48299e-05
Average (10000 runs) elapsed time, iterator= 7.35307e-05
```

The results are much more uniform now, and now the non-iterator method is the fastest! Any insights? Or even this result is meaningless and I should do some more test?

the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using get_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

int main() {
    double time1,time2,time3;
    int run=10000;
    for(int k=0; k<run; k++){
    //Read the array elements
    std::vector <int> v;
    int input,N=100000;
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++){
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    int sum1{0},sum2{0},sum3{0};
    auto start = get_time::now();
    for(int i=N-1; i>=0; i--){
        sum1+=v[i];
    }
    auto finish = get_time::now();
    auto time_diff=finish-start;
    std::cout << "Sum= " << sum1 << " " << "Elapsed time,non-iterator= " << std::chrono::duration<double>
        (time_diff).count() << " Seconds" << '\n';

    auto start2 = get_time::now();
    std::vector <int>::reverse_iterator ri;
    for(ri=v.rbegin(); ri!=v.rend(); ri++){
        sum2+=*ri;
    }
    auto finish2 = get_time::now();
    auto time_diff2=finish2-start2;
    std::cout << "Sum= " << sum2 <<" Elapsed time, reverse iterator= " << std::chrono::duration<double>
        (time_diff2).count() << " Seconds" << '\n';

    auto start3 = get_time::now();
    std::vector <int>::iterator i;
    for(i=v.end()-1; i>=v.begin(); i--){
        sum3+=*i;
    }
    auto finish3 = get_time::now();
    auto time_diff3=finish3-start3;
    std::cout << "Sum= " <<sum3 << " Elapsed time, iterator= " << std::chrono::duration<double>
        (time_diff3).count() << " Seconds" << '\n';
    time1+=std::chrono::duration<double>(time_diff).count();
    time2+=std::chrono::duration<double>(time_diff2).count();
    time3+=std::chrono::duration<double>(time_diff3).count();
    }
    std::cout << "Average (" << run << " runs)" << " elapsed time, non-iterator= " << time1/double(run) <<'\n';
    std::cout << "Average (" << run << " runs)" << " elapsed time, reverse-iterator= " << time2/double(run) <<'\n';
    std::cout << "Average (" << run << " runs)" << " elapsed time, iterator= " << time3/double(run) <<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What optimization level did you use to build that?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I used this command: clang++ -std=c++14 filename.cpp and then ./a.out

Comment: Also, use many more elements then you currently are.  A blip in another process could affect your timings since they are so small.  You really should check over a 100,000 elements  or more to get a nice average.

Comment: @Arghya then the benchmark here is invalid. Any number you got there is meaningless. Try compiling with `clang++ -std=c++14 -O3` at least. Also, as  @NathanOliver said, try with 100,000 element to have relevant amounts of data.

Comment: also you should make a larger number of measurements. Strictly speaking measuring once is as good as measuring zero times, because you have no control over what your uncertainties are

Comment: Benchmarking can be hard to do right.  If you are interested in more on the topic here is a very good video/start of the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk

Comment: If you are measuring this with an unoptimized build your results are meaningless. Add a `-O2` or `-O3` in there with your compiler options and try again.. also (as mentioned) benchmark *a lot more* than a single execution.

Comment: You are measuring cout.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot  Please see the updated answer post.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the video link, I will check it out. Also please see the answer post.